# How can I skip n items from laravel eloquent collection?

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

Why this is not working?

```
$myFriends =Friend::where('status',1)->pluck('user_id');
$users = User::Where('active',1)->WhereNotIn('id',$myFriends)->get();     
$users =$users->skip(2)->take(3);
```

> > it gives following error
>
> ```
> BadMethodCallException in Macroable.php line 74:
> Method Skip does not exist.
> ```

Comment: What is at Macroable.php line 74 ?

Answer (score 23):

Use `slice` method instead of `skip`.

```
$users->slice(2)->take(3);
```

Or in a shorthand:

```
$users->slice(2, 3);
```

It skips 2 first records and returns next 3 records.

---

With respect to @ikurcubic's comment The answer updated.

Comment: This call can be simplified with `$users->slice(2,3);` From [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-slice): If you would like to limit the size of the returned slice, pass the desired size as the second argument to the method.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the forPage collection method instead.. You just need to enter the page number and the number of items you want respectively..

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-forpage

```
$chunk = collect($users)->forPage(2, 3);

logger($chunk->all());
```

Comment: The only problem with this is that it does not totally imitate the take and skip in eloquent. In eloquent skip(0), returns the first page, but when using forpage(0,8) returns the last page.

Answer (score 1):

once you call "->get()", it's no longer the query builder instance where you can use "->skip()" and "->take" and even other queries like "->where" and such ..

If you want, you must call it before you call the "->get()" so you should call as:

```
$users = User::Where('active',1)->WhereNotIn('id',$myFriends)->skip(2)->get();
```

or

```
$users = User::Where('active',1)->WhereNotIn('id',$myFriends)->skip(2)->take(3);
```